# MYSQL: help joining three table

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables:

**role**
rid, name

**usr_role**
uid, rid

**usr**
uid, username, firstname

I want to join usr table with role table and list all roles names for all users in third column, separated by commas

For example

```
uid, username, firstname, roles
1, user1, name1, role_name1, role_name2
2, user2, name2, role_name3, role_name4, role_name 5
```

I am able to just join the tables by doing the:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.uid AS userid, u.username AS Username,
                u.firstname AS Name, r.name AS Role 
FROM usr u LEFT JOIN usr_role 
  ON  u.uid=usr_role.uid LEFT JOIN role r 
  ON r.rid=usr_role.rid
```

but I seem to be stuck further

Comment: In general, it's best to handle problems of data display in a presentation layer, if that's available - eg a simple loop in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT u.uid AS userid, u.username AS Username, u.firstname AS Name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(r.name) AS Role
  FROM usr u LEFT JOIN usr_role ur
    ON u.uid = ur.uid LEFT JOIN role r
    ON ur.rid = r.rid
 GROUP BY u.uid, u.username, u.firstname
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf7e8a/2)

Sample output:

```
| userid | Username |      Name |        Role |
|--------|----------|-----------|-------------|
|      1 |     john |      John | role1,role3 |
|      2 |     jane |      Jane |       role2 |
```